# How to colorize specific strings in powershell textbox

Tags: powershell, colors

How to colorize specific strings in text box in powershell forms. I don't use any "studio" applications.

Output for example:

```
Searching...
a - found
b - Not found
c - found
```

Expected result:

```
Searching...
a - found
b - \red\Not found\red\
c - found
```

I heard about `RichTextBox`, but when using the code bellow it doesn't print anything, just an empty string(no errors appeared from code)

```
$StatisticsBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox 
    $StatisticsBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,30) 
    $StatisticsBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,320) 
    $StatisticsBox.MultiLine = $True 
    $StatisticsBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
    $StatisticsBox.ReadOnly=$True
    $Form.Controls.Add($StatisticsBox) 

$StatisticsBox.SelectionColor = 'red' <---- also tried "color.red"
$StatisticsBox.text = "`r`nNot Found:`r`n" + $StatisticsBox.AppendText("colored stirng") + "`r`n" +$StatisticsBox.text
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

[image]

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Width = 300
$Form.Height = 200

$StatisticsBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox 
$StatisticsBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,30) 
$StatisticsBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,100) 
$StatisticsBox.MultiLine = $True 
$StatisticsBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$StatisticsBox.ReadOnly=$True
$Form.Controls.Add($StatisticsBox) 

$StatisticsBox.SelectionColor = 'red'
$StatisticsBox.text = "`r`nNot Found:`r`n" + $StatisticsBox.AppendText("colored stirng") + "`r`n" +$StatisticsBox.text

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
$Form.Dispose()
```

[POSHGUI](https://poshgui.com/) is always my first stop for these.

Comment: Wow. really weird...I am getting an empty string

Comment: What's your OS and $PSVersionTable.PSVersion? I'm no GUI wiz but I have a few machines around that might match your setup. Seems to also work on a Win7 machine with PS ver 2.

Comment: Windows 10, PS 5.1. Build 16299, Revision 64

Comment: That's newer than any build I have. Maybe your .NET Framework version? Works for me on machines with .NET versions 4 and 2.